# Getting our dirty words into one place

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have tags for all of the following:

[taboo](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taboo), [vulgar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vulgar), [offensive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive), [expletives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/expletives), [obscenity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obscenity), [euphemisms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euphemisms), [pejorative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pejorative), [swearing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swearing), and [insults](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insults)

This is a bit... excessive. So I'm now accepting suggestions for a word to bundle all of these together and avoid so much duplication. Also mention any other tags that need to go in the same bucket.

(HT to both RebeccaChernoff and RegDwight for bringing this to my attention.)

Comment: I thought 'euphemism' didn't necessarily belong but we have used it only on questions that could easily be grouped in, except one (Profs & Students) where it would make sense to remove the tag I think.

Comment: Possibly related tags: profanity, perjorative, homophobia, chinglish. Related on the euphemism end: slang, vernacular, buzzword.

Comment: philosophically speaking, you might ask how we got in this situation in the first place...

Comment: @Jeff We *could* ask that, but I'm pretty sure it would be a different question then. Of course, it would still be a good question for Meta, so feel free to ask it.

Comment: _Dirty_ _words_? There appears to be some sort of Moral Majority panic going on on this site.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would keep [euphemisms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euphemisms) and [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language), as there is a difference between an euphemism and an offensive word. for example, *downsizing* can be a euphemism for *cuts*, but *cuts* is not an offensive word; it's just a word that in that context is avoided.

Comment: I go for this. If we later decide we want to move [tag:euphemism] into the other, we can.

Answer (score 5):

My personal preference would be for either [vulgarity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vulgarity) or [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language) as the root tag, with all of the above as synonyms.

Comment: I like [tag:offensive-language] more than vulgarity since it seems to me a more generic grouping - vulgar always makes me think of common.

Answer (score 4):

I think a single tag could rule them all: [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language). Vulgarity is covered in that, and euphemism is really not relevant as euphemisms in this context are avoidances of offensive language.

Answer (score 4):

I renamed [offensive] to [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language).

Then I merged the following into [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language) and created synonyms mapping them to [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language):

- [taboo]
- [vulgar]
- [expletives]
- [obscenity]
- [pejorative]
- [swearing]
- [profanity]

Many of these questions had several of these tags already, which further speaks to the fact that having all of these tags was unnecessary.

I did not touch:

- [euphemisms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euphemisms)
- [insults](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insults)

Comment: This is great. If you add a rule to exclude questions tagged with offensive-language from the supercollider, will Jeff leave us alone?

Answer (score 2):

I would also support [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language) as a root tag for most of this. However, I would say to keep [insults](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insults) separate; insults are not necessarily offensive to listeners, just the subject. "Dumber than a box of rocks" is an insult, but no censor would consider it "offensive". And yes, keep [euphemism](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euphemism) separate, as the the word for which another word is euphemistic does not have to be offensive.